# ¿Cómo dibujar con un QPainter en un QWidget secundario dentro del widget principal?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Bueno, lo que estoy intentando es, dentro de la ventana de la aplicación, crear un QWidget sobre el cual pueda dibujar una imagen con un QPainter, la imagen en cuestion será rellenada con otro QPainter, mi código compila pero no aparece el la imagen dentro del widget. El archivo .h:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class QPainter;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

protected:
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QPainter* auxPainter;
    QImage* auxImage;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

El archivo .cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <qpainter.h>
#include <QPaintEvent>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->auxImage = new QImage(ui->widget->size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    this->auxPainter = new QPainter(auxImage);


QPen lapiz;
lapiz.setColor(QColor(Qt::black));
lapiz.setWidthF(2.5);
this->auxPainter->setPen(lapiz);
this->auxPainter->drawEllipse(15, 15, 10, 10);
update();
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter base(ui->widget);
    base.drawImage(0,0,*(auxImage));
    event->accept();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete auxPainter;
    delete auxImage;
    delete ui;
}
```

Por qué sucede eso? Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Explica mejor lo que deseas hacer, no se puede dibujar un widget desde otro widget, solo se puede pintar en su metodo paintEvent

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas pintar un widget solo se debe hacerlo en su método `paintEvent()`. Una solución es crear otro widget y promoverlo para que use el widget de Qt Designer, para ello sigue los siguientes pasos:

- Crear una clase que herede de QWidget
- Haz click derecho sobre el widget y selecciona `Promoted Widgets`
- te aparece un cuadro de dialogo, en ella debes indicar la clase del widget y la ubicacion de la cabecera(.h).
- Despues aprietas el boton add y promote.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de ello, sobreescribes su metodo paintEvent.

En el siguiente [enlace](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/123525-es) hay 2 ejemplos.